# Wrapping Gesture detector around a card

Tags: flutter

Right now i have a button on the body of the page but cannot implement this button (that routes to a different page) to just encapsulate just the card that is

```
child: new Text(data["data"][index]["title"]),
```

it is inside of an itemBuilder so i thought i had to do a GestureDetector. Ive tried to put that child into the GestureDetector method but cannot get it to work unless its the whole body.

```
@override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Listviews"),
        ),
        body: new GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder:  (context) => StandardsControlPage()),
            );
          },
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: new ListView.builder(
              itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data["data"].length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return new Card(
                  child: new Text(data["data"][index]["title"]),
                );},
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }}
```

This example wont work if i have multiple buttons to press with different routes, and was wondering If there is anyway to implement a button with that route to just that child, how would i do it?

Comment: So you have tried putting Card in the GestureDetector. And it is not working?

Comment: would i put it after return new card( ---- or would i put it before it, it seems everytime i put it after the itemBuilder it seems to mess up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return new Scaffold(
    appBar: new AppBar(
      title: new Text("Listviews"),
    ),
    body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: new ListView.builder(
        itemCount: data == null ? 0 : data["data"].length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return new GestureDetector(
            child: new Card(
              child: new Text(data["data"][index]["title"]),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => StandardsControlPage()),
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    ));
```

I think this will work.